# How to use phpdocs outside of classes?

Tags: php, eclipse, class, phpdoc

I recently discovered, that you can have phpdocs outside of classes and your IDE (like Eclipse) would autocomplete it.

For example:

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?> <div><?php echo $this->app()->name; ?></div>
```

Eclipse would autocomplete `$this->`

I found this code snippet in a framework, but I can't find any documentation about this type of phpdoc. Has anyone a link for me? I didn't know, this was possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In eclipce I know this way ([Eclipse completions - @var (PHPDoc) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014837/eclipse-completions-var-phpdoc-question)):

```
$that = $this;
if (false) $that = new Controller();
```

And use $that

But it should work in phpStorm IDE (with @var phpdoc)